# Oracle 12 OleDB connection from 32 bit ASP application on 64 bit Windows 2012

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oledb, 32bit-64bit

I run into an this issue and I have been hitting my head against the wall trying to figure out how to get around it. I have an ASP.NET application (written in .NET 1.1 I believe, with no source code available) that connects to Oracle database via OleDB connection.

The host machine has been recently replaced with a 64 bit Windows 2012 and the Oracle database upgraded to v 12. Now, the only way I have been able to get the application to run on the new server is if I switch Application Pool on IIS to run in 32 bit mode. Everything seems to work - except for the connection to Oracle.

The connection string that I use is:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source=DSNAME;User ID=user;Password=password;Unicode=True
```

When I try to run a simple ASP.NET test web app in 64 bit app pool mode just to test out the connection - it works fine! When I switch into 32 bit mode - it returns the following `The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

Now, I have tried downloading and installing the 32 bit version of Oracle Data Access Components and running the install.bat and configure.bat (which seem to have executed without any errors - yet provider is still not working!

Also when I run the following command line (to launch 32 bit OleDB config screen)

```
C:\Windows\syswow64\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll",OpenDSLFile D:\test.udl
```

I get `Provider can not be found. Ensure provider has been installed properly.` message prompt.

Please help!

Comment: Can you know if IIS server has both 32 bits and 64 bit ODBC versions? I'm not sure but I suppose IIS only have 64 bit in your case.

Comment: If you like to switch between 32 bit and 64 bit, you have to install both Oracle Clients, 32 bit and 64 bit. Follow this instruction to do this: [Stack Overflow - Install Oracle x86 and x64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that is working if you switch to 32 bit mode is because, you probably have 32 bit version of the driver, like mention by Wernfried. You need to install 64 bit version of the driver. Remove 32bit version if you don't need it.